# Is RAID 1 on a home PC useful?

Tags: raid, raid-1

Is [RAID 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID#RAID_1) on a home PC useful?

Comment: What you're essentially asking is "is it useful to have a live, mirrored copy of my data on a home PC".  It depends on *your* particular needs, there is no possible answer to this question.  Personally, I maintain my backups manually, but I definitely know some home users that need the high redundancy RAID-1 provides.

Answer (score 8):

I have a RAID 1 setup on my high end computer so I don't have to worry about one hard drive failing and resulting in a ton of downtime for my work.

RAID 1 is great for home, since you can have one disk fail and still have your data protected. Just slap a new disk if one fails, and let your system do a rebuild. I recommend RAID 1 to most of my clients because the downtime from replacing a drive and installing a new OS is so great.

Just remember **RAID is NOT a backup solution!** It is a good solution to prevent a single hardware failure from taking your data with you, but not from things like Viruses and other users erasing your data. You still need to copy your data to a second source, preferably offsite, as often as your data changes.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if you want to get faster drive read performance and be able to survive a disk failure.

You can find more information on read/write performance and fault tolerance properties of RAID on the [wikipedia page for Standard Raid levels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels#RAID_1)

Comment: I think on a home computer it's more a matter of reliability than read performance ...

Comment: RAID-1 is faster *read* performance, at the cost of slower *write* performance.